# What is the size limit enforced by browser on <input typ="file">?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, http-post

While trying to upload a large image using  the image files is not included in the POST to the server. 
Any ideas for making sure the file is sent to the server in the POST request?

Comment: You probably need to set your `enctype` on your form element to `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: it is unexpected behavior place your forms html

Comment: @vcsjones: I have already included that

Comment: do you mean it worked for small files?

Comment: Limit is not on the client, it is normally set on the server.

Comment: @tcoder: Yes, It works perfectly for small files

Comment: What is the language/framework are you running on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to say what the *server* is since that is what specifies the limit. Generally speaking, POST requests don't have defined limits - though for non-file POST entries, some **browsers** *do* place limits, sometimes around 2MB.

Tell us the server type and we can tell you how to change the limit (assuming that it is a server you have some control over). It would also be helpful to tell us the file size you are expecting to transfer.

Comment: The server is running python/django. Also, I am trying to upload / transfer 1.2 MB file

Comment: thanks a lot! That helped. Since I was seeing a different photo being sent in the request which made me believe there was some browser enforced limit

Comment: No worries. @epascarello seems to have given the settings you need. I'm not all that familiar with Django. If, however, Django is set to the 2.5MB default and it is still not working, perhaps you have something set in your web server - let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Just like what I said in the comments, it has nothing to do with the browser, it has to do with the setting on your sever.

It is in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/?from=olddocs

> **Changing upload handler behavior**
>
> *Three settings control Django's file upload behavior:*
>
> `FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE`
>
> The maximum size, in bytes, for files that will be uploaded into memory. Files larger than FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE will be streamed
>   to disk.
>
> ```
> Defaults to 2.5 megabytes.
> ```